# Mockito keeps returning Empty List

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I'm working on unit testing a method in Mockito and mockito keeps sending an empty zero size list even when I have initialized the list that is to be returned.

This is the code to be tested. Note that nonCashIncludedPaymentPlanActive is always true ( Mocked ).

```
    List<DebtAccountTransaction> debtAccountTransactionList = null;

    boolean nonCashIncludedPaymentPlanActive = balancingPlanService.checkNonCashIncludedPaymentPlanParameter(debtAccountId);


    if (nonCashIncludedPaymentPlanActive) {
        debtAccountTransactionList = debtAccountTransactionDao
                .getDebtAccountTransactionListByDebtAccountIdListWithCN(baseDebtIdAccountList, null);
    } 
    if (debtAccountTransactionList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new SfcException("DISPLAY.PAYMENT_PLAN_WITH_NO_BALANCE_SERVICE_FILE_CLOSED");
    }
```

This the statement that keeps returning a List that I have mocked in mockito and added an item to it and here it returns an emptylist.

```
debtAccountTransactionList = debtAccountTransactionDao
                .getDebtAccountTransactionListByDebtAccountIdListWithCN(baseDebtIdAccountList, null);
```

which then ofcourse gets caught by this line

```
if (debtAccountTransactionList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new SfcException("DISPLAY.PAYMENT_PLAN_WITH_NO_BALANCE_SERVICE_FILE_CLOSED");
    }
```

Thus inorder to avoid this path of execution I have done the following in Mockito:

```
when(debtAccountTransactionDao.getDebtAccountTransactionListByDebtAccountIdListWithCN(baseDebtIdAccountList, null)).thenReturn(
            debtAccountTransactionList);
```

and declaration of debtAccountTransactionList is :

```
DebtAccountTransaction debtAccountTransaction = spy(DebtAccountTransaction.class);
    debtAccountTransaction.setId(2L);


    List<DebtAccountTransaction> debtAccountTransactionList = new ArrayList<DebtAccountTransaction>();
    debtAccountTransactionList.add(debtAccountTransaction);
```

I tried mocking a List, tried different argument captors but nothing seems to work. When I debug it, Mockito does fill up the *debtAccountTransactionList* but with an empty List, thus it fails.

Any help with how I can make sure that Mockito sends a Non-Empty Non-Zero List so that it can bypass the *isEmpty()* check.

Comment: The Problem is not with creating the Mocks, the problem is with debtAccountTransactionList is being returned as Null or Zero Size.

Comment: When using a collection (as it appears to be) make sure that the collection is of the same type and that the elements in there have a proper equals/hashcode implementation. Else Mockito will not see it as a match and return an empty list (the default behavior).

Comment: The problem is the mock creation/behavior registration. This doesn't match what you put into the method and hence returns to the default behavior of returning an empty list.

Comment: could please post the entire test class with dependencies, annotations ?

Comment: I see, can I match it for any List<Long> argument passed to the *debtAccountTransactionDao.getDebtAccountTransactionListByDebtAccountIdListWithCN(baseDebtIdAccountList, null)* 

I mean instead of baseDebtIdAccountList, I want it to accept Any Long List. I tried using argument matchers but they dont seem to work and cause errors. I also have a copy of baseDebtIdAccountList in the code so is there any way to check to make sure baseDebtIdAccountList is equal to the baseDebtIdAccountList I passed in.

Comment: Entire Test Class is about 2K lines of code, can't say I can post it all.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are correct, I tried the test without my line of code for stubbing the method call and returned the default empty list. 

Any way to match this argument correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is the mock creation/behavior registration. This doesn't match what you put into the method and hence returns to the default behavior of returning an empty list.

as pointed out by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum?tab=profile)

Thus there was a problem in acceptance of the argument by Mockito and it would ignore my stubbing and then return an empty list by default.

I fixed it by making sure the object that is **baseDebtIdAccountList** passed to the function  *when(debtAccountTransactionDao.getDebtAccountTransactionListByDebtAccountIdListWithCN(baseDebtIdAccountList, null)).thenReturn(
            debtAccountTransactionList)* is exactly the same in the rest of the code. Thus there was a mismatch in the arguments and Mockito used the default way of using an empty list.

Answer (score 6):

A good rule of thumb in writing tests, especially with a mocking library like Mockito: Don't confuse stubbing with verification. Stubbing (`when`) is about getting your system under test (SUT) into the desired state, *not* about *asserting* anything about how the SUT behaves.

In Mockito, the way to make assertions about how the SUT behaves is *after* the SUT runs, using `verify` calls. If you don't have any `verify` calls, you're not actually asserting anything, and your SUT can misbehave without your test catching it, which is obviously a bad thing.

As a result, it's usually best to make your matchers for stubbing (`when`) as broad as possible, since the goal of stubbing is just to make sure you fall into the right test case. For example, you can and often should use matchers like `any()` in your `when()` call. If you did that, you would sidestep the issue you're having here.

If you want to make assertions about the values that the SUT actually used as arguments, do that with `verify`, or possibly by capturing the value and making additional assertions about it directly.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about that. I tried using any() or anyListOf() or other matchers but I couldn't understand the syntax of using it correctly as Mockito, if you have any resource on understanding it's syntax that would be great.

Yes I do the verify calls after preparing the SUT and I'll keep note of preparing my SUT in as broad terms as possible.

Plus if you have a book to suggest on mockito or unit testing, it would be really helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: There are lots of books out there; I don't have a good recommendation off the top of my head. If you have specific instances where `any()` gives you a compiler warning or error, feel free to ask those on Stack Overflow. More generally, learning how Java infers and resolves types at compile time is valuable. I definitely recommend reading the Java Language Specification for the version of Java you're using -- it's a bit of a dense read but I don't think it's hard to understand, and it is the definitive reference.

Comment: Worth noting, too, that despite first appearances, Mockito isn't "magic": all Mockito objects and functions obey the same rules and limitations of any other objects in the language. They just communicate with each other in hidden ways to give the illusion of "magic". Once you understand what e.g. `when` is doing, it won't be nearly as confusing.

Comment: no worries, I'll definitely ask about any errors on Stack Overflow and will go through the specification! :)

Comment: I also highly recommend reading Martin Fowler's article [Mocks Aren't Stubs](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) for good background on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put in any place of the code something like:

```
debtAccountTransactionDao = Mockito.mock(NameOfTheClassOfThisDebtAccountObject.class);
```

?

You should put something like this before calling the method `getDebtAccountTransactionListByDebtAccountIdListWithCN`, so it knows it should use the mocked behavior, not the normal behavior of the method (that could be return an empty list).

Comment: Yes, that has done, but it wasn't the source of the problem :)

Comment: Thank you Matteo, really useful info for beginners :)